# Why would the following query return an error message? (can someone explain in detail please)

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Why would the following query return an error message

```
SELECT date, quantity, hardwareID
FROM orders
WHERE hardwareID =
SELECT hardwareID 
FROM hardware_parts
WHERE description LIKE '%DRIVE%';
```

Comment: I would encourage you to get familiar with the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html

Comment: Could you please share your error message?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a subquery as an expression it has to be in parentheses.

```
SELECT date, quantity, hardwareID
FROM orders
WHERE hardwareID =
    (SELECT hardwareID 
    FROM hardware_parts
    WHERE description LIKE '%DRIVE%');
```

Also, this will only work if the subquery returns one row, since `=` can only compare with one value. If it can return more than one row, you need to use `IN` instead of `=`, or join the tables:

```
SELECT o.date, o.quantity, o.hardwareID
FROM orders as o
JOIN hardware_parts as p ON o.hardwareID = p.hardwareID
WHERE p.description LIKE '%DRIVE%'
```

Comment: Depending on the cardinality between the tables, the `JOIN` solution might multiply the rows of `orders`. `IN` (or `EXISTS`) would be a safest choice.

Comment: Or use `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicates. I avoid `IN (SELECT ...)` because in my experience MySQL often suboptimizes it.

Comment: @Barmar . . . The better solution is `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1):

Error 1: the subquery must be enclosed with parenthesis.

```
SELECT date, quantity, hardwareID
FROM orders
WHERE hardwareID = (
SELECT hardwareID 
FROM hardware_parts
WHERE description LIKE '%DRIVE%'
                    );
```

Error 2: the subquery may return more than one row, IN operator needed.

```
SELECT date, quantity, hardwareID
FROM orders
WHERE hardwareID IN (
SELECT hardwareID 
FROM hardware_parts
WHERE description LIKE '%DRIVE%'
                    );
```

The last form is syntactically and logically correct but slow - WHERE EXISTS or JOIN are more useful.